# DQL results in Excel

Tags: documentum

I am running a DQL statement in Documentum dql editor and get 3000 rows back. Is their any way I can export the rows returned by DQL  to the excel spreadsheet?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s no easy way to export data from the DQL editor- instead use a tool, e.g. FME dqMan - basic features like exporting to Excel is free.

Answer (score 0):

As Henning Winter said -  there is no easy way unless you use some tool which has features or you can write the DFC code to execute the query. You have to iterate the query result and write in the EXCEL sheet using some opensource APIs.

Comment: I have DQMan on my computer. I used that.